# Why was one question accepted, while another, similar question received very negatively?

Tags: support

Earlier this year, I asked how to keep myself and my family safe by escaping from a high-risk COVID country. The post was received very negatively and was eventually deleted. The moderators declined my flags against those who posted negative comments. Eventually, the question was deleted, and I was banned from posting questions.

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161569/where-can-i-travel-to-receive-a-covid-vaccine-as-a-tourist) asks how to get a COVID vaccine. It is, essentially, the same question, yet that question was received positively.

What's the difference? Does it matter that one question was asked by a moderator?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Could you reference which post was deleted? [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155180/leaving-major-cities-during-covid-19-pandemic?r=SearchResults) with a very similar tone was well accepted by the community.

Comment: The question you've linked currently has both upvotes and downvotes and many comments including some which (to me) seem to suggest it's pointless asking the question at this stage.

Comment: @JonathanReez No, because it was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why was one question accepted, while another, similar question received very negatively?

This has been observed from time to time, and the main answer is:

1. People can vote whichever way they want. There is [no accountability whatsoever when downvoting for no reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355329/178179).
2. There is a [mob mentality](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6756/1810): people tend to be influenced by the early vote.
3. Questions about traveling during covid have received mixed results. Some people [complain that some of these questions are immoral (~ "shouldn't be traveling during covid")](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6740/1810), despite the fact that this is travel website.

For example,  [Am I allowed to go to the airport to catch a flight if I am supposed to self-quarantine in California, United States?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158793/1810) has a score of `-6` whereas the [same question about another state](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159740/1810) has a score of `+7`.

TL;DR: Don't expect any consistency on this website.

Comment: And recently with [the mask question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/183224/27701), same thing, plus comment deletion showing a severe moderator bias for masks. Even now, in late 2023!

Answer (score 1):

One can only speculated about the reason for upvotes, but one of them might be question being off-topic.

Questions about emigration are off-topic, since we have Expatriates for them. Question about travelling for vaccination are about medical tourism, which is a port of travel (thought its on-topicness might be disputed).

Another reason might be usage of s-word. What is safe is opinion-based, and question with that swear word in the title are usually quite bad one, so the folks are prejudiced before even reading the content.